# iText 7 throwing InlineImageParseException in the first PDF page while in iText 5 it works perfectly

Tags: .net, exception, itext, itext7

I am using iText 7.1.1 for .Net Core 2.0. When I try to get text from the first page of a PDF I get the following exception:

```
iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Util.InlineImageParsingUtils.InlineImageParseException: 'Cannot find image data or EI.'
```

Code:

```
pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDocument.GetFirstPage()); //throw InlineImageParseException
```

All other pages except the first works perfectly in iText 7.

Using iText 5 no exception is thrown and the first page is converted to text perfectly.

PDF File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16P-__xlugJoVK8QUifNzfMfaZp9DIMK9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I could reproduce the issue using iText for .Net while there is no problem using iText for Java. The problem might be related to the issue described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48386827/1729265) as the inline images in your case use RLE compression.

Comment: I didn't understand very well. Should I edit the RunLengthDecodeFilter method to solve the problem? Overwriting or editing direct in source code?

Comment: I propose fixing the filter as described in that referenced answer and trying again.

Comment: I now actually debugged the code, and the situation is even worse than I thought, the `RunLengthDecodeFilter` in iText 7 for .Net is not merely slightly off (as per the referenced answer) but completely broken.

Comment: So the correct path to this problem would be direct report to the iText team. But as they recommend using stackoverflow for this kind of problem, I no longer know what to do. I'll have to look for another library, maybe Docotic.PDF.

Comment: I was thinking, would the problem really be the implementation of RunLengthDecodeFilter? We can not forget that the problem do not happens with version 5 of iText. The problem appeared in version 7. 
I really can not do much about it. I do not understand anything about PDF, I just need to convert PDF's to text for data manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the issue in question is that the `RunLengthDecodeFilter` is completely broken in iText 7 for .Net. The current (7.1.2-SNAPSHOT) code looks like this:

```
public class RunLengthDecodeFilter : IFilterHandler {
    public virtual byte[] Decode(byte[] b, PdfName filterName, PdfObject decodeParams, PdfDictionary streamDictionary
        ) {
        MemoryStream baos = new MemoryStream();
        byte dupCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++) {
            dupCount = b[i];
            if (dupCount == (byte)0x80) {
                // this is implicit end of data
                break;
            }
            if (dupCount >= 0) {
                int bytesToCopy = dupCount + 1;
                baos.Write(b, i, bytesToCopy);
                i += bytesToCopy;
            }
            else {
                // make dupcount copies of the next byte
                i++;
                for (int j = 0; j < 1 - (int)(dupCount); j++) {
                    baos.Write(b[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return baos.ToArray();
    }
}
```

This looks very much like the iText 7 for Java version which is no surprise as the iText 7 for .Net code is nearly completely an automatized translation of the corresponding Java code.

Unfortunately here the automatized translation ignores a fundamental difference between Java and .Net: While the Java type `byte` means a *signed* byte, the .Net type `byte` means an *unsigned* byte.

Thus, in Java `dupCount >= 0` is only true for 0x00..0x7f but false for 0x80..0xff. In .Net, though, it is always true.

So the different interpretations of those byte value ranges in Java (which corresponds to the PDF RLE definition) is completely ignored in .Net (which consequentially does not correspond to the PDF RLE definition anymore). This causes iText 7 for .Net to be unable to even properly recognize the *extent* of inline image data.

As the page content stream of the PDF shared by the OP contains many inline images all (or at least most) of which use run length encoding, this iText 7 for .Net bug keeps it from making sense of the contents which eventually causes the exception observed by the OP.

The OP also mentions that for iText 5 the issue does not occur. Looking at the iText 5 .Net code one sees that the .Net type `sbyte` (*signed* byte) is used there (cf. e.g. [the code quoted in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48386827/1729265)). Thus, the iText 5 .Net code at least correctly recognizes the extent of inline image data so it doesn't fail with an exception.

The bug explained in that referenced answer still exists both in the iText 5 and iText 7 code, but as the OP is not interested in the inline images as such, this bug does not disturb him.

Comment: Thanks, mkl!
Issue is fixed in the latest snapshot version and will be included in the release of iText 7.1.3.